# Laravel does not check the authorization when attempting to subscribe a private channel

Tags: laravel, broadcast, pusher

I have newly started working with [laravel broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting) and faced a problem. I am using Pusher and I want to check if users are authorized to subscribe to a private channel. Users' access to posts' comment notification is authenticated but not authorized. I am trying to send notification of new comment only to the post's author but all authenticated users who have opened the post get notifications. Am I missing something or what?

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewCommentEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $comment;
    public function __construct($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('post-'.$this->comment->post_id);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'new-comment-event';
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['comment' => $this->comment->comment];
    }
}
```

**routes/channel.php:**

```
<?php

use App\models\Post;

Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('post-{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return false;
    //return $user->id == Post::find($id)->author_id;
});
```

**And the JavaScript in view:**

```
var pusher = new Pusher('904d58ankty8c8397d000', {

        authEndpoint: 'http://localhost/blog/public/broadcasting/auth',
        cluster: 'ap2',
        forceTLS: true,
        auth: {
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-Token': "{{csrf_token()}}"
            }
        }
    });

    var privateChannel = pusher.subscribe("private-post-{{{$post->id}}}");
    privateChannel.bind('new-comment-event', function(data) {
        $('#post-comments').append('<p>'+data.comment+'</p>');
    });
```

By the way the following is the provider code:

```
public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth']]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

The laravel version i am using is: 5.8

Comment: It seems like the channel.php routes are not called at all.

Answer (score 0):

What does "$this->comment->post_id" denote? If it denotes the id of that particular post, then who ever has access to that post will get the notification. Get author_id from post_id and Broadcast on 'post-'.author_id.

Comment: Yes it is the id if a particular post. and No, a private channel (in this case: private-post-3)  is supposed to authenticate users (which now does) and check if authorized too.

Comment: Will you be subscribing to all the posts to get a post's comment? Right now who ever is subscribed to that post_id will get that notification. If you want only author to get the notification, use author_id in the channel name.

Comment: That is what i expect from my channels route:
`Broadcast::channel('post-{id}', function ($user, $id) {
 return $user->id == Post::find($id)->author_id;
});`

Comment: Oh..ok. I suggest broadcasting as author_id is better. See which ever seems fit.